# Binomial Expansion conditions for valid expansion $\frac{1}{(1+4x)^2}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

I was studying Binomial expansions today and I had a question about the conditions for which it is valid.

$$\frac{1}{(1+4x)^2}$$

I was asked to find the binomial expansion, up to and including the term in $x^3$.

Now, this is how I did the expansion.

$$\frac{1}{(1+4x)^2}$$ 
$$=(1+4x)^{-2}$$
$$ = 1 + (-2)(4x) + \frac{(-2)(-3)}{2}16x^2 + \frac{(-2)(-3)(-4)}{6}64x^3 + ...$$
$$ = 1 -8x + 48x^2 -256x^3 + ...$$

Now, the text I am reading says

***Expansion is valid as long as $|4x| < 1 ⇒ |x| < \frac{1}{4}$***

I'm confused. 
How did the text come to this conclusion?

[image]

Comment: The expansion $$\frac1{1+u}=\sum_n(-1)^nu^n$$ upon which yours is built, is valid for $$|u|<1$$ Is this clear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the term in $x^n$ you will find that it is $(n+1)\cdot (-4x)^n$. Therefore if $|x|\ge \frac 14$ the terms will be increasing in absolute value, and therefore the sum will not converge.

The easy way to see that $\frac 14$ is the critical value here is to note that $x=-\frac 14$ makes the denominator of the original fraction zero, so there is no prospect of a convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\frac{1}{(1+4x)^2}={\left (\frac{1}{1+4x} \right)^2}$, and it is convergent iff $\frac{1}{1+4x} $ is absolutely convergent.